# facebook app token instead user token php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, sdk, token

i don't know why when i'm using facebook php sdk **3.1.1** on **codeigniter** with following code:

```
...
...
$this->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
$config = $this->config->item('facebook');
$this->load->library('facebook', $config);

echo $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
....
```

i retrieve app access token instead ( the correct ) user access token.
infact when i try to call

```
$this->facebook->api('/me')
```

php return me an error like this

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in
>   **/srv/www/...**

i've try to change library version until 3.0, but nothing changed

Anyone know something about that?

Answer (score 2):

`/me` returns your personal profile info. If you want to query `/me`, you need to authenticate via a user access token, which is above the app level access token.

Peruse at your leisure: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Yep i know, is what i do....maybe it doesn't work because i'm in a facebook page tab?  

So library can't access variables `$_REQUEST['code']` and `$_REQUEST['state']`

Comment: To get `/me` to work, you need to "sign in" to your app as a Facebook user - which tells Facebook that it's okay to share your own personal information with the app you created.This is different from your app access token. Read through the documentation - it'll help.

Comment: **Resolved**. To fix this i have to call `$this->facebook->getAccessToken();` after facebook library load In the `__construct()` method of my controller.  
By this way facebook sdk retrieve the correct access token and store it in a session.

Thanks.